# YouTube videos automatically set to mute

Tags: youtube, google-chrome, audio, mute

YouTube videos have all started playing with the audio slider set to mute. I can slide the volume on for each video to hear the audio, but when opening a new video it's also automatically set to mute.

[image: YouTube mute]

How can I get videos to automatically play with volume enabled?

<sub>I'm using Chrome on Windows 7, without any external Flash installed (just Chrome's built-in version).</sub>

Comment: Are you using any sort of Chrome extension that adds to/modifies YouTube functionality?

Comment: +1 I am also having this issue. Ubuntu + Chrome. Started yesterday.

Comment: Noticed as well on Chrome with no extensions

Comment: Tested it on IE Win8.1.(Dont have any plugins running on IE) Maybe its a YoutTube bug...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a YouTube bug. According to Google employee ytKeane, [it's is a known issue](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/youtube/ETfCgHO4MhU/2xuLhOZfFoAJ). His or her reply in the Google Product forum is as follows:

> Thanks for your patience, all. We have been aware of this issue. It should be resolved soon.
>
> While this issue is live, please try clearing your browser's cache and cookies, or the workaround:
>
> The mute will keep coming back for each video you watch, but you can get your sound back each time by pausing the video, right clicking the little X by the speaker symbol and then clicking the speaker symbol itself.  Then start the video again.  Kind of a pain, but at least you can hear the videos until the problem is fixed.